# Javascript/Express - Serving images to client

Tags: javascript, express, browserify

I have a webapp set up using browserify that displays images. When you mouse over the image I want to display a picture that is sent to the client when all files are bundled. How do I go about accessing this?

```
<img src="STOCK_IMG" onMouseOver={(e)=> e.target.src="../public/img/sound-recording.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below sets the image source on mouse over, is this what you are looking for ?

```
<img src="STOCK_IMG" onmouseover="this.src='../public/img/sound-recording.png'">
```